# android: How do I highlight a MenuItem programatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Setup:

So in our app we have one Activity and each feature is on it's own fragment.  We navigate from feature to feature (fragment to fragment) using a NavigationDrawer.

Issue:

When a web service fails in one of our features we need to navigate from that fragment back to the main feature fragment.   Right now we are doing this using a interface callback to the mainActivity.  The problem is that in the NavigationDrawer the old feature is still select not the new, currently open feature.  How can I programmatically highlight any MenuItem I want?

Or is there a way I can pro programmatically click on the MenuItem I want to navigate to it?

Comment: this line of code fixed the issue, It has to be called after the view is finished being created.   mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_canvass).setChecked(true);